# Image Classification error

Tags: arcmap

When I run the maximum likelihood classification it shows that the task has been performed but there is no output. However, 3 files can be seen in recycle bin namely input, output and error every time I run the tool.

There is no error message seen.

I'm not saving the output starting with a number as name. The name that I'm using has less than 8 letters

Software: ArcMap; Version: 10.6

[image: Image showing the Maximum Likelihood Classification is complete]

[image: Parameters used]
[image: Files in recycle bin]

Comment: @user2856 Thanks. Will try this and share the results

Comment: @user2856 I tried running the tool with individual bands but still got the same result as mentioned above

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1j9F-9ttHH1HKOECIu9qzo7mmlbxMFtzm?usp=sharing
I have added the signature file and the raster files I'm using to perform the Maximum Likelihood Function on Google Drive
@PolyGeo

Comment: I'm not a potential answerer of this question due to its topic but even if I was I never follow links to obtain test data.